# Best wiki product that supports LDAP and markdown?

Tags: git, markdown, wiki

We have a number of wikis in git repos that our security offer wants moved to an on-prem solution.

Whilst git Enterprise would be the smoothest transition it is pretty pricey when you've got a lot of users, and is a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut when all we're doing is wikis.

Its also a bit clunky when you want to add images to your wiki articles.

Can anyone recommend a good wiki product we can run on-prem that support LDAP for single sign-on, makes adding images easy, and supports markdown so we don't have to edit the mark-up on our wiki documents?

Answer (score 1):

[Gitlab Community Edition](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce).

We integrated it with our Active Directory, and any git repo you make has a wiki automatically with markdown and file storage/linking. Even the wiki itself can be managed by git. While it isn't ideal to make a git repository purely so you can access it's wiki as a secondary feature, it's super easy and we use it at work to tremendous effect.